# How to make Duplicate Posts and Pages in multi sites - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make duplicate posts and pages on wordpress either by functions or a plugin, any suggestions.

Also, i want to use these duplicacy for multi site functionality. That is, if i create another site, it may inherit the posts and pages of master site.

Comment: what was there to do -1.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the built in export/import feature.  Under the tools menu in the admin menu you can find these two options.  Just export the posts and pages XML file.  Then on your new site or multisites you can import that XML file.  You'll have an option to download all media on import also, which will bring over the images, PDFs, etc.

Here's the documentation:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen

http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Import_Screen

Comment: thanks for your answer but this i have to do manually. Actually when I am creating another site, i just want these posts and pages to be copied at that site.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm not sure if there is an automated way of doing this.  I did some checking online and came up empty as well.  The only solution I've ever used is the export/import feature.

Answer (score 0):

I have a subsite that contains the base setup for a new site.I use the "Multisite Cloner" plugin on the master site to specify that 'template' subsite whenever new subsites are created.

For duplicating posts/pages, you could use the export/import process.

But there is now (4 years later from your question) a plugin that allows you to duplicate a page or post from one subsite to another: Multisite Post Duplicator (https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-post-duplicator/ ). I have not used it yet (although I will be testing it soon), but it has good reviews and appears to be maintained.

I add this info now (four years later) because this question came up in a search for a similar need.